# Paint child window that overflows outside top-level window

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to paint my child window that overflows outside its parent top-level window? I've seen combo-boxes can do this when their drop down is taller than the top-level window.

For example:
[image]

My window is a custom class with the style flags `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW`. From what I understand I could use `WS_EX_LAYERED`? Or I could make the window taller and transparent to give the appearance of the window overflowing but those transparent areas either side of the red overflow are going to be Windows Message 'blackholes' that would really annoy the user if they click there expecting to be interacting with a different top-level window.

Comment: Comboboxes do it with a popup window that overlays the parent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks that will work great

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to paint my child window that overflows outside its parent top-level window?

No. By definition, a [child window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#child)

> [...] is confined to the client area of its parent window.

But that's not what you need anyway. If you want to mimic the behavior of a combo box control, you need to create an owned pop-up window instead (see [Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows)).